# use cloud datastore api for partial property updates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am exploring Cloud Datastore rest api .
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/
If I commit an entity (as update or upsert) with just one property, all existing properties are deleted.
It seems the only way to update an entity is to first fetch it then update a property and then save it. 
Is there any better way to just update some properties in an entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there is currently no way to update a specific set of properties of any entity. All commits to the Datastore assume you are sending a "whole" entity.